# How do I change the size of an input field dynamically based on the size of the placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a string that will serve as a URI for an API dynamically, and based on user input for URL Parameters etc.

There are nested EventListeners that I am using to capture the text input I need to build the resource string and that string is what I am placing in a read only text field for the user to copy/paste as needed.

My issue is that after the last event listener captures the user's input, the function I am using to resize the placeholder's text field, does not capture the length of the last string needed and it fails to resize the text field accordingly. The function resizes the field enough to capture the second to last string of user input.

This is the function I am using to resize the placeholder text field:

```
function fieldSize(){
    // Script to change the size of the resource field based on the length of the value
    $("input[placeholder]").each(function() {
        // Bug Must fix
        $(this).attr('size', (($(this).attr('placeholder').length)));
    });
}
```

Here is the nested even listeners I am using to build the size of the text field. You can see the fieldSize() function being called in the innermost Event Listener:

```
// Function to dynamically generate Endpoint Resource for Token Create Notification
function endpointResourceCreateToken(){
    // Dynamically change placeholder value depending on URL & Query Parameters
    $("#eventID").on("input", function(event) {
        var tridInput = ($("#inputTokenRequestorID").val() || "").trim();
        var trefidInput = ($("#inputTokenReferenceID").val() || "").trim();
        var eventTypeInput = ($("#eventType").val() || "").trim();
        var eventIDinput = ($("#eventID").val() || "").trim();

        //if any of the fields are blank, return and don't do anything
        if (!tridInput || !trefidInput || !eventTypeInput || !eventIDinput) return;

        // Build URI Resource and display to DOM
        $("#resource").attr('placeholder', "/vtis/tokenRequestors/" + tridInput + "/tokens/" + trefidInput + "/tokenChanged?eventType=" + eventTypeInput + "&eventID=" + eventIDinput);
        fieldSize();
    });
}
```

Here is the html where I am embedding the different scripts needed to build the endpoint and resize the field storing the URI:

```
// Endpoint Resource
                    "<strong>Endpoint Resource</strong>" +

                    "<script>" +
                        // Call script to piece together endpoint
                        "endpointResourceCreateToken()" +
                    "</script>" +

                    // Endpoint for user
                    "<div class=\"form-group\">" +
                        "<input id=\"resource\"class=\"form-control \" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Please Enter URL & Query Parameters\" readonly>" +

                        "<script>" +
                            "fieldSize()" +
                        "</script>"
```

How do I capture the length of the last string of input in order to properly size my placeholder text field????

Thank you!

Comment: You realize you are creating event bindings inside other event bindings inside other event bindings inside other event bindings .... ?  Duplicate event bindings means a given event for an element will be processed multiple times.  And depending upon how you bind them, they may operate upon different values.  You should always try to avoid creating duplicate event bindings on elements to avoid these issues.

Comment: What would be a better way to deal with the multiple inputs I need to capture? Will one handle all of them? Or should it at least?? I think I did it that way because it didn’t capture the event on the remaining inputs...

Comment: Instead of nesting the bindings, just check if all the inputs have a value at the point that you need them all to have a value.  If any don't, don't perform your logic.  Nothing about your logic keeps a user from going back and removing input after they have entered some in, so you aren't even safeguarding against that issue with this approach.

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/fdc7d325/1/

Comment: Thanks for the input just left the office so I’ll test it when I get home. If you want to put it as an answer I’ll accept it if you want the points

Comment: No problem.  See if it resolves your issue first.  I'm not hard up for points, :)

Comment: Its a sweet solution to the event binding problem and I like how elegant the solution is, but its still does the exact same thing in regards to the fieldSize issue. It's almost as if its not capturing the length of the last query parameter to adjust accordingly....